# How to add a filter to selection field in odoo

Tags: odoo-9

I need to add a filter to a selection field in odoo..

```
roomuser = fields.Selection([('stpi', 'Belongs to Park'),('Incubation', 'Belongs to Incubation companies'),('both', 'Belongs to Park& Incubation companies')],'Room Assignment',required=True)
roomType = fields.Selection([('meeting','Meeting Room'),('discussion','Discussion Room'),('auditorium','Auditorium'),('board','Board Room')],required=True)
```

Here i need to filter the value of roomType based on the value of roomuser. Suppose roomuser value is both only auditorium and board should be visible in roomType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made my comments as below , kindly request you to find it as below it may help in your case:

```
class HotelManagement(models.Model):

    _name='hotel.management'
@api.model      
def _get_room_type_list(self):
    # [('meeting','Meeting Room'),('discussion','Discussion Room'),('auditorium','Auditorium'),('board','Board Room')]
    vals=[]
    for record in self.env['hotel.management'].search([]):
        if record.roomuser in ['stpi','Incubation']  :
            vals.extend([('meeting','Meeting Room'),('discussion','Discussion Room')])
        if record.roomuser in ['both'] :
            vals.extend([('auditorium','Auditorium'),('board','Board Room')])
    return vals


def _get_roomuser_list(self):
    return [('stpi', 'Belongs to Park'),
                            ('Incubation', 'Belongs to Incubation companies'),
                            ('both', 'Belongs to Park& Incubation companies')]


roomType=fields.Selection(string="Room Type", selection=_get_room_type_list, default='meeting', required=True)
roomuser = fields.Selection(string="Room Assignment",selection=_get_roomuser_list ,required=True)
```

Here i have just put  @api.model  on top _get_room_type_list and  traversing all the record in this(hotel.management) model and filtering the selection field .

Comment: I tried this code. But the field roomuser giving multiple values in the selection list, as meeting room, discussion room, board,auditorium are coming in multiple times

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer ? I don't think there is a way to do what you want to do.